# Troubleshooting PHP Mail Function

Tags: email, sendmail, php

How do I troubleshoot PHP's mail function? The code below (obviously I have my actual email address in there) outputs **ERROR** and I DO NOT receive the message:

```
if(mail("email@address.com","test subject","test messaeg"))
    echo "SENT";
else
    echo "ERROR";
```

My php.ini has the default settings that CentOS 6.3 minimal is setup with:

```
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
mail.add_x_header = On
```

I tried the following via SSH, and it worked fine. I received the message to my gmail account:

```
echo "Body text." | mail -s "Hello world" email@adderss.com
```

Where should I go from here in troubleshooting this?

Comment: Do you mean you received the "test subject" email but the script outputs ERROR? Or do you mean you received the "Hello World" email?

Comment: I received the hello world email fine. The test subject email doesn't come to me. I never receive it. the script just outputs ERROR.

Comment: Check your error logs.  Sometimes, PHP mail errors are logged wherever your `error_log` directive points.

Comment: You could always set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before the mail function to see what the error is as well.  Let us know what you find.

Comment: I tried that, didn't report anything. It ended up being SELINUX somehow messing with it. I'm not really sure what about it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

Had to disable SELINUX using the instructions here: http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html